# Image processing events

Tags: algorithm, image, events, image-processing, computer-vision

I’m interested in segmentation, feature detection, image processing algorithms, etc.  I’ve done a few searches on the internet about conferences or seminars that would be interesting and more importantly helpful to connecting with other people in my field.  Any suggestions on the best US conferences that deal with image processing?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of good conferences, most sponsored by IEEE, like CVPR(Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition) and ICIP (International Conference on Image Processing).  Both CVPR and ICIP usually has a minimum amount of exhibitors; so if you want to listen to speakers and not get lost in a sea of exhibitors, these are for you.  ASPRS has one on Imaging and Geospatial Technologies. There is also the SAIM Conference on Imaging Science next year in May.

I’ve used this [website](http://iris.usc.edu/information/Iris-Conferences.html) several times.  It has basically every conference and event relating to image processing and computer vision in the US and international.  The author keeps everything up to date and nicely organized.

My company, Wolfram Research, is holding a few [image processing events](http://www.wolfram.com/events/image-processing-2011/) on a much smaller scale.

Comment: Adriana, so perhaps you know [`this user`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/813036/matthias-odisio)